# SP Not Found When It Clearly Exists

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I copied a database from a live MSSQL server to my local one, and was able to log in correctly. I am having a problem however in that when it is time to call a stored procedure the Asp.Net application keeps telling me the SP does not exist, when it clearly does.

I am using windows authentication but on the server I was using credentials, could this be the problem?

Also, all of the SP's have my online username attached to their name, as in `username.StoredProcedurenName`.

Please help I have been trying to fix this for hours.

I just noticed that when I attempt to run the SP from the SQL Management Studio it works, but it appends the username to the SP such as:

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [username].[SPNAME]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

If I remove the username, it says the same thing (SP not found). How do I get around this?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to SSMS using Windows Authentication to run the stored procedure in a query window?

Comment: Yes, it works if I log in manually from SQL Management Studio. This is really weird!

Comment: And it's the same account using SSMS as well as process owner for the ASP .NET web application?

Comment: If it doesn't find it when called with one part names then check what your default schema is. It is best practice to use two part names anyway though rather than implicit name resolution.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: Martin how do I check the default schema and what does it need to be sat to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are calling your stored procedure without specifying the schema.  When calling a stored procedure (or accessing a table, view, etc) that's not in the default schema that your account is configured for, usually dbo, you need to explicitly include the schema like the sql command below

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("username.StoredProcedurenName", mySqlConnection);
```

Comment: Tell me how to change the schema then; I don't want to change every SP name in my program.

Comment: I decided to make all my SP names fully qualified.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper using fully qualified names is the better approach, it avoid any potential confusion and readies your app to handle the potential for multiple schemas in the same db in the future

Answer (score 1):

It's likely what Jason said. The solution has to do with rights and ownership. When you see the SP in the SQL Management Studio, under Programmability->Stored Procedures, your SP should have a prefix like "dbo." or "GateKeeper."

If the SP has "dbo." as the prefix, the user account with which you're connecting to the DB just be part of the database owners (dbo) group, otherwise you won't have access to it. So, you can either add the user to that group, or create the stored procedure ("create procedure spBlahBlah as ..") using the account to plan to run the program under; when you call it you use "exec GateKeeper.spBlahBlah" to stipulate the Schema.StoredProcedureName.

Those are your two choices.

Comment: Yes I understand, but this is just a temporary offline database so I need a quick fix to get it to run. When I create a new SP with my acc it is created as `dbo.SPNAME`, but all the others show up as `TheGateKeeper.SPNAME`. I do not with to use fully qualified names, so how do I change the default schema of the current account to TheGateKeeper so it runs the SP?

Comment: Sorry for the late response .. I'm in Europe. Since we're just talking about a temp, off-line DB, probably the easiest approach would be to add TheGateKeeper to the DBO group and make sure that any SPs are created by the DB owner, or any member in the dbo group. So, script then delete all the SPs marked TheGateKeeper.SP, and re-create them as someone in the dbo group. By doing that, you'll always have dbo rights and you'll be able to run the SPs without stipulating the schema ... everything will be dbo.